# Why is my github portfolio only showing the readme file and not my project?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I'm a new web developer so I don't have much experience with this. I deployed my react app using https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f. At the end after I npm run deploy, everything goes well but the link provided only shows a readme. How do I fix this?
portfolio chaselipscomb$ npm run deploy

```
> portfolio@0.1.0 predeploy /Users/chaselipscomb/Documents/WD/portfolio
> npm run build
```

My repo is here: https://github.com/chaselipscomb/chaselipscomb.github.io/tree/master

```
> portfolio@0.1.0 build /Users/chaselipscomb/Documents/WD/portfolio
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

File sizes after gzip:

  48.08 KB  build/static/js/2.fd53cf75.chunk.js
  2.63 KB   build/static/js/main.0a8dd3db.chunk.js
  1.5 KB    build/static/css/main.f4645d51.chunk.css
  772 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.c7cc6e23.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at http://chaselipscomb.github.io.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy


> portfolio@0.1.0 deploy /Users/chaselipscomb/Documents/WD/portfolio
> gh-pages -d build

Published
```